# How do i ensure my webpages are being cached with spark-framework

Tags: html, browser-cache, spark-framework

My web application is powered by Java Spark framework
The user makes a httppost request, we process the request and generate the page, clearly the page we send back is not cached and we would not want it to be.

But in its header it refers to various css, js and img  files, these do not change. How do I ensure that these pages are cached, how do I even check if they are being cached, I dont currently know if they are or not.

```
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style/googlefonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="style/songkong.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="style/jquery/ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="style/jstree/themes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="style/songkong.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="style/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="style/jquery/ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="style/jstree/jstree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="style/songkong32.png" type="text/png">
  <link rel="icon" href="style/songkong32.png" type="text/png">
</head>
```

Comment: You control the caching of these assets with the HTTP response headers you serve each individual file with. You would start to inspect this with your browser's developer tools' network inspector.

Comment: @deceze im using Firefox, found network inspector but nothing to help me, I dont specifically create response headers for any files and even when i generate html page i dont see how I can set http response for a  file I just refer to in a link href ?

Comment: You configure such things in your web server, which will serve the files with the appropriate headers.

Comment: The jetty webserver is hidden I dont interact with it explicity. Okay take something simpler if I just open a local html page using file:// protocol so there is no webserver how do I ensure files are cached in browser (rather than reloaded from filesystem)

Comment: You already mentioned Firefox's network inspector. The first column you see is called ```Status```. It shows an icon followed by some HTTP status code. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and search for ```Network request column``` to find a reference which tells you which icon means that the respective resource was cached.

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber okay thanks It doesnt seem to be caching anything because status is always coloured green circle and there is always a value in transferred column, I would have though things like images would be cached by default ?

Comment: okay i think I have fixed it, adding Spark.staticFiles.expireTime(600) then caches these files, thanks

Comment: Most browser's dev tools have an option that disables cache while dev tools are open. This option for Firefox's dev tools can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Java Spark Framework to cache static files referred to in html pages  you need to set the expireTime (in seconds) on the staticFiles class

e.g

```
Spark.staticFiles.expireTime(600)
```

caches for 10 minutes

By default **there is no caching**

Since non static files are generally being dynamically created with Java Spark I am not sure if there is any need to cache anything else.